# Monitor resolution using NvApi

Tags: c++, nvapi

I'm using the following function to get information about the monitors I connected to my pc:

```
NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedDisplayIds(hPhysicalGpu[DisplayGpuIndex], 
                                  pDisplayIds, 
                                 &nDisplayIds, 
                                 0);
```

How can I get the correct resolution of each of them based on the id? I looked on the NvApi documentation but couldn't find the corresponding function. Furthermore I know the MSDN functions that can solve this problems but then I have to match the two information using monitor names. This is not a good option because the monitor type may change, and then I remain with my hard coded monitor types ...

Comment: You will have major headaches matching any NvAPI and Win32 IDs. They should be thought of as completely orthogonal. LUID has come along in later version of D3D to solve some of these headaches when it comes to matching adapters with displays.